# Split an image into Hue Saturation and Value layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Either using an online tool, or in Photoshop, is there a way to separate an image into pure Hue Saturation and Value layers?

For example, I can get just the values by desaturating an image completely. Is there a process that does the same but for hue and saturation?

Answer (score 1):

There is a plug-in from Adobe called HSBHSL that converts between RGB color channels and HSL channels. Use the filter, reset the appropriate color channels, then convert back to RGB.

Download it [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/en/photoshop/kb/optional-file-format-plugins.html) and, after installation, you can find it in the filter category called Other.

Comment: Is there not a Mac version?

Comment: I found one. Is there a way to actually get the hue channel to show up as colors? i.e. It maps red to grey and blue to a black. Is there a way to remap those back to colors? I'm trying to visualize the hue and values independently in an image.

Comment: Have you tried cranking up saturation to max on your original layer? That should give you the hues if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: That's actually really close, but the problem is that it doesn't eliminate value from the formula.

Comment: I just realised that if you use the HSBHSL filter you can reset the saturation and value channels (yes, go to channels) and then convert back. That should give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: what do you mean when you say "reset" saturation and value? I'm kind of new to working with channels.

Comment: Filling them with black, white or perhaps gray. Unfortunately I'm on my phone and can't double check these things.

Comment: Corel Photo Paint have those channels :o(

Answer (score 1):

**Hue:** Set the image layer's Blend Mode to *Hue*, add a layer below it filled with pure red (#ff0000, or any other fully saturated colour).

**Saturation:** Set the image layer's Blend Mode to *Saturation*, add a layer below it filled with pure red, view the Red channel.

**Value:** Image / Adjustments / Desaturate.

(This is just for visualisation - proper converters usually adjust for the subjective appearance of the brightness of different hues.)