# How to convert color gradient to grayscale?

Tags: gradient, image-editing

[image]

This is an image of the gravity of earth. I need it in grayscale with the white areas representing max gravity and black areas representing the minimum gravity so I can get a displacement map to use in Blender. I got the image in this red to blue gradient, there was no grayscale already. I need to map the colors to a linear grayscale gradient like this.

[image]

I don't even know how to approach this. A simple desaturation or HSV channel split obviously doesn't work. How would I do it? I would prefer it to be done in GIMP, Blender or Python -- whichever works. Thank you!

Comment: Nothing clever here, but you can index the the colors of the original map and then change the palette. Unfortunately no idea how to do it by scripting. A programmer is needed. I'm afraid no included automatic palette sorting will generate the right index numbers (to be used as greyscale) for the colors because the color gradient isn't monotonic by hue, saturation nor brightness. Manual palette generation should be possible, but the job is tiresome. BTW  the apparent non-monotonicity can be caused by the low resolution of the screenshot we have . You have the original data, so check it.

Comment: I think you're right. I didn't really consider it before, but the hue channel is surprisingly smooth or monotonic and looks very accurate for what I'm looking for. It makes sense since there's a smooth gradient from red to green to blue. There were a few artifacts which I was able to clone away. BTW, here's the high-res images in case anyone was interested in them https://imgur.com/a/DhkMnEV

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop:

Preface -- I don't know what's high or low in the color image.

`Image > Adjustments > Gradient Map`

[image]

If this is incorrect and the high/low are wrong... just tick the `Reverse` option on the **Properties Panel**.

[image]

---

I don't know if Gimp or Blender offer similar features to Photoshop's Gradient Map.

Comment: Yes, GIMP has a gradient map function: *Colours > Map > Gradient map*. It works using the currently selected gradient (in the Gradient tool options).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is convert hues into grayscale values. If you have Photoshop, [there's a plugin that can do this for you](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/114051/161575). Just change your image into HSL mode and the data you want will be in the H (hue) channel.

I can't verify this because I don't have Photoshop. However, I do have Python, which can be made to do a similar job. Here's some code I wrote to transform an [image from NASA's website](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/images/3666/earths-gravity-field). You'll notice I've rotated the h values slightly to avoid the extreme red end of the spectrum coming out as ever-so-slightly blue. You might not need to do this with your image.

```py
def rgb2hsl(src):
    import colorsys
    from PIL import Image
    im = Image.open(src)
    pixels = im.load()
    w = im.width
    h = im.height
    for y in range(h): # for every pixel:
        for x in range(w):
            (r,g,b) = pixels[x,y]
            r /= 255.0
            g /= 255.0
            b /= 255.0
            (h,s,v) = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r,g,b)
            h += 0.1    # (slight hue rotation to avoid image artifacts)
            if h > 1.0:
                h -= 1.0
            r = g = b = int(h * 255.0 + 0.5)
            pixels[x,y] = (r,g,b)
    im.save(src+".hsv.png")

rgb2hsl("PIA04652_lrg.jpg")
```

Here are the results:

Input:
[image: Earth gravity map rendered in false colour]

Output:
[image: Same image after converting hue to luminance]

Comment: Doesnt seemvery accurate.

Comment: @joojaa Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with the images. One is the bad compression artifacts you have. See if you can find another source with uncompressed images.

The other is that the scale is not planned to be decomposed.

The obvious choice is to use the hue channel. Let me decompose it for you.

[image]

The white artifacts on the right side are due to the high compression of the original file. See if a non-compressed file is somewhere. One problem is that red is at the border of being white or black on the hue channel.

Not we should invert the image.

[image]

And play with levels to fix the values of black and gray.

I used a curve like this:

[image]

Then apply the same method and the curve on the actual elevation map.

There is a slight color that probably is not resolved properly, and that is the second problem.

If we see the red channel, there is a slight drop of value at the end of the gradient. "Dark red".

[image]

It is present on the other channels, so I am not sure how that would react on the real hue gradient. Just keep that in mind if you need a really precise rendering. You probably need to generate your own elevation map. See if there is some form of raw data.